# CakePHP home page - cache not working

Tags: cakephp

In my CakePHP home page, I get the message:

**Your cache is NOT working. Please check the settings in APP/config/core.php**

I googled for possible solutions, some of which were to uncomment the Cache.check and Cache.disable line. Even then the error isn't resolved.

Also the webserver runs on www`-`data (exec('whoami');) whereas my home folder is public`_`html. How do I change www`-`data to public`_`html?

Comment: now I got the cache running.. I had deleted that folder by mistake.
but the web server run on www-data? Is that ok?
I am working from my home folder in public_html. I have all the files in public_html only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides, check if you have the original directory structure inside /app/tmp/cache.

Recently I had the same problem, and found out that for some reason my /app/tmp was empty. Redoing the directory structure helped.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your cache is set to file, make sure your /app/tmp and all the folders inside are world-writable (drwxrwxrwx).